# Advanced coordinate rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, rotation, trigonometry

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Game2 extends Sprite {

        var balls:Array;
        var radius:Number = 50;
        var centerX:Number = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        var centerY:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        var i:int = 0;
        var angle:Number = 0.1;
        var sin:Number = Math.sin(angle);
        var cos:Number = Math.cos(angle);
        public function Game2() {
            init();
        }



        function init():void
        {
            balls = new Array();
            for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                var ball:Ball = new Ball(10, 0x00FF00);
                var xposition = centerX + Math.cos(i / 8 * Math.PI * 2) * radius;
                var yposition = centerY + Math.sin(i / 8 * Math.PI * 2) * radius;
                ball.x = xposition;
                ball.y = yposition;
                addChild(ball);
                balls.push(ball);
            }

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            for(i = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
            {
                var ball:Ball = balls[i];
                var x1:Number = ball.x - stage.stageWidth / 2;
                var y1:Number = ball.y - stage.stageHeight / 2;
                var x2:Number = cos * x1 - sin * y1;
                var y2:Number = cos * y1 + sin * x1;
                ball.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 + x2;
                ball.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 + y2;
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Can someone explain the work of this formula?:

```
var x2:Number = cos * x1 - sin * y1;
var y2:Number = cos * y1 + sin * x1;
```

i just can't figure it out, if we edit it like this:

```
var x2:Number = x1 - y1;
var y2:Number = x1 + y1;
```

all the balls are moving so fast and get out of screen bounds, and also why if we change it like this:

```
var x2:Number = cos * x1 - sin * y1;
var y2:Number = cos * y1 + sin * x1;

or

var x2:Number = cos * x1 - sin * y1;
var y2:Number = cos * y1 + sin * x1;
```

it will work equal, as far as i understanded is that here happens some kind of simetry, if we are on the left or right sides the velocity x == 0 and y is at the maximum velocity of its position the y slows down each time he get closer to the top or bottom, if we are on the top or bottom the velocity y == 0 and x is at maximum speed of his position then also slows down each time he gets closer to the right or left sides, i traced it, but i can't understand why we have to multiply it by cos and sin, i've traced this moments but still can't figure it out, can anyone explain this moment?

Comment: PS: the author of the book that writed about this formula also not understands fully how it works...

Comment: "if we change it like this [...] it will work equal" -> The formulas are equal. A typo?

Comment: i mean the will rotate around the center anyway if we change the steps of the formula

Comment: Nothing is changed in the formulas after "if we change it like this". That's what I'm wondering about.
BTW: I added the rotation and trigonometry tags to your question. Although they don't have much followers, maybe someone stumbles upon this question and has some sources that explain the rotation matrix easier than the Wikipedia articles. Unfortunately, I only know a [german Youtube video](http://youtu.be/8QnR1V0EMKE?t=12m09s) that explains the rotation matrix very well.

Answer (score 2):

The two formulas represent a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) multiplied with a vector.

Comment: can you explain it in your words?

Comment: @Zecrow Within this matrix [trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) are used to calculate the rotation of the vector. What exactly do you not understand?